# jquery: have a certain css on mac safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

Got some kind of a f up on the page, where one div shows in a way it's not supposed to only on mac safari. Figured, it will be easier to use a jquery hack, rather than redoing the whole thing.

Used this code to target mac safari, but it doesn't work. Can someone, please, point out the mistake?

```
if((navigator.platform.indexOf(“Mac”) != -1) && (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie|trident/i))) {
 $(".hiddenlg img").css('display','none');
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac")`. See the quotes there?

You've to use `""` and not `“”`.